# Aggregate initialization of a class that privately inherits an aggregate class in C++11

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, aggregate-initialization

Consider the following code:

```
struct base
{
    int x, y, z;
};

struct derived : private base
{
    using base::base;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    base b{1, 2, 3}; // Allowed
    derived d{1, 2, 3}; // Not allowed
}
```

The line `derived d{1, 2, 3};` makes my compiler (Clang 3.3) fail with error "no matching constructor for initialization of 'derived'". Why is this? Is there any way to initialize `derived` via aggregate initialization?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`derived` has a base class, so it's not an aggregate (§8.5.1/1: "An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with [...] no base classes [...]").

Since it's not an aggregate, it can't be initialized with aggregate initialization.

The most obvious workaround would probably be to add a `ctor` to base, and have the ctor for `derived` pass arguments through to `base`:

```
struct base
{
    int x, y, z;

    base(int x, int y, int z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
};

struct derived : private base
{
    derived(int a, int b, int c) : base(a, b, c) {}
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    base b{1, 2, 3}; // Allowed
    derived d{1, 2, 3}; // Allowed
}
```

Of course, that doesn't work if you're set on `base` remaining an aggregate.

Edit: For the edited question, I don't see a way to use an `std::initializer_list` here -- `std::array` doesn't have anything to accept an `initializer_list`.

Comment: Ah, I feel like an idiot now. I'm guessing the only workaround is to add a constructor to `derived` that takes an initializer_list and constructs `base` with that?